# How to find unequal values in two columns using exel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have column F and column G Ranges from `F19:G500`. Suppose if, the value in `F19` is not equal to the value in `G19`, and the `G19` value is > 0. Then I want to get a msgbox “unmatching numbers”.

I wrote a VBA code, as shown below, which includes the rows `F19`, `F20` ,`F21`, but writing code for every single rows up to 500 rows, is very a difficult task.

So how can I minimize this code for all rows?

```
Sub UM()

Sheets("cbpb-de").Select
If Range("f19").Value <> Range("g19") And Range("g19").Value > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Unmatching  Number  " & Range("f19").Value & "  and  " & Range("g19").Value
Else
    If Range("f20").Value <> Range("g20") And Range("g20").Value > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unmatching  Number  " & Range("f20").Value & "  and  " & Range("g20").Value
    Else
        If Range("f21").Value <> Range("g21") And Range("g21").Value > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Unmatching  Number  " & Range("f21").Value & "  and  " & Range("g21").Value
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through rows 19 to 500 using a loop. Using `Cells` method you will specify cells to compare: `Cells(rowIndex, colIndex)` - `rowIndex` will be the iterator, which will go through rows, `colIndex` will be `6`, if the column is `F` (sixth column), `7` if the column is `G`. If the conditions are not met, you will print a message saying in which row the issue occured.

```
Sub Matches()

For i = 19 To 500
    If Cells(i, 6).Value <> Cells(i, 7).Value And Cells(i, 7).Value > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unmatched numbers at line: " & i
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .

Answer (score 0):

The below code will do what you need. Rather than hardcoding tests (which will take a long time for around 500 rows) you instead need to loop through your range and test the values. More information can be found on looping can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264596.aspx

I have purposely assigned the values in columns F and G to variables to help you understand how loops work and to make it easier to keep track of the values as they change.

```
Sub Test()
Dim c As Range
Dim varG As Variant
Dim varF As Variant

    'Loop All Cells In Your Range
    For Each c In Range("F19:F500")
        'Get The Value Of The Current Cell In Column F
        varF = c
        'Get The Value Of The Current Cell In Column G
        varG = c.Offset(0, 1)
        'Is There A Value In Column G?
        If varG > 0 Then
            'Yes, There Is A Value. Does F = G?
            If varF <> varG Then
                MsgBox "Unmatching number " & varF & " and " & varG & " address " & c.Address
            End If
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks u sir.. This is what I was looking for, worked perfectly  very helpful it even traces a row address in msgbox…